# asp.net mvc3 rc2 app deployed to hosting crashes, how can i find out why?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crash, hosting

I deployed my asp.net mvc app to hosting and under real load it sometimes restarts. My guess is that it crashes.
What are my ways of finding out why it does so?

my primary candidates are my Session[] and Application[] code.
and maybe not disposed DbContexts.

But there should be a way to know why app restarted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried setting up Elmah on your website?

This should let you see where your problems lie.

You can install it via Nuget -> `install-package elmah`.

Make sure you secure it though so that Joe Public can't see it.

Comment: I did, but I've yet to figure out how to make it persist info between app restarts. So, basically, when crash occured - there is an empty list of errors in elmah. )-: